# How to solve infinite repeating exponents

Tags: puzzle, exponentiation

How do you approach a problem like (solve for $x$):

$$x^{x^{x^{x^{...}}}}=2$$

Also, I have no idea what to tag this as.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Assume first that the identity holds. The you will have $x^2=2$. Since $x$ should be positive, we have $x=\sqrt{2}$. Now it remains to prove that this value is really a solution. You may consider a sequence $a_{n+1} = \left(\sqrt{2}\right)^{a_n}$ to give a rigorous proof.

Comment: Thanks for this comment. I overcomplicated this problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convergence of tetration sequence.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/890319/convergence-of-tetration-sequence)

Comment: @SangchulLee Why X should be positive? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm just going to give you a HUGE hint. and you'll get it right way. Let $f(x)$ be the left hand expression. Clearly, we have that the left hand side is equal to $x^{f(x)}$. Now, see what you can do with it.

Comment: Note, though, that the argument that you have in mind only shows what the only possible solution is. The argument fails if the righthand side is $4$, say, as there is then no solution. The lefthand side converges iff $e^{-e}\le x\le e^{1/e}$.

Comment: $x^{f(x)} = 2, f(x)ln(x)=ln(2), f(x) = ln(2)/ln(x)$, since $f(x) = 2, ln(2)/ln(x) = 2$, solving for x gives $e^{ln(2)/2}$?

Comment: @Matt. Dito. And even further, you may notice that $e^{\frac{ln(2)}{2}}=e^{ln(\sqrt{2})}=\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: I see. Thanks for the hint/help!

Comment: Correcting my earlier comment: It does not fail when the righthand side is $4$. The restriction on $x$, however, is correct.