# What is the derivative of $x!^{x!^{x!^{x!^{x!^{x!^{x!^{.{^{.^{.}}}}}}}}}}$

Tags: derivatives, power-towers

What is the derivative of $$x!^{x!^{x!^{x!^{x!^{x!^{x!^{.{^{.^{.}}}}}}}}}}$$

---

**My effort:**

Let $$g(x)=x!^{x!^{x!^{x!^{x!^{x!^{x!^{.{^{.^{.}}}}}}}}}}\implies g(x)=x!^{g(x)}$$
Taking natrual log on both sides,
$$\ln(g(x))=g(x)\cdot\ln(x!)$$
Differentiating,
$$\frac{1}{g(x)}\cdot g'(x)=g'(x)\cdot\ln(x!)+g(x)\cdot\frac{1}{x!}\cdot x!\cdot\psi^{(0)}(x+1)$$
$$\implies g'(x)\left[\frac{1}{g(x)}-ln(x!)\right]=g(x)\cdot\psi^{(0)}(x+1)$$
So does isolating $g'(x)$ give me the correct solution? If not, how can I solve for the differential?

Edit: The gamma function is indeed implicitly assumed when the factorial function is used.

Comment: @Brenton no, he isnt. He multiplies by the derivative to the right, which is correct. He says the derivative is $\frac{1}{x!}\cdot x!\cdot\psi^{(0)}(x+1)$

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen Sorry, I missed the $\psi$ term.

Comment: What is $x!$ for $x$, say, $\sqrt2$?

Comment: @PrzemysławScherwentke $x!=\Gamma (x+1)$ ([Gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function)).

Comment: @PrzemysławScherwentke he clearly defines it as $\Gamma(\sqrt{2}+1)$... he uses the derivative of the gamma function in his proof

Comment: ^He probably is playing loose with the definition $\Gamma(x+1) = x!$.

Comment: @JimmyK4542 True, but his steps seem fine as long as one defines the factorial that way. Integer values should match at the very minimum

Comment: @user236182 I know this relation. I was simply afraid that it may be a formal differentiation on naturals.

Comment: @PrzemysławScherwentke perhaps, but it should hold anyway given that definition. I can't find anything wrong with it simply due to the use of the Gamma function

Comment: Right. I primarily wrote my working based on the fact that Euler's Gamma function and factorial function evaluate to the same value for positive integers (With a difference of 1 in the argument of course... since $\Gamma(n+1)=n!$)

Comment: If he intends a gamma function, he should write it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your definition of $g(x)$ does not make sense for $x! \gt e^{(1/e)} \approx 1.44467$ because it does not converge as seen in the answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/890319/convergence-of-tetration-sequence) and [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1089458/how-can-i-prove-the-convergence-of-a-power-tower).  It is less than this [in about the ranges](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=gamma%28x%2B1%29%3De%5E%281%2Fe%29) $-4.970 \lt x \lt -4.103$ and  $-0.380 \lt x \lt 1.614$.  Within those ranges, you are doing fine.

Comment: Clear. Thanks for the heads up!

Comment: What if he wanted to allow complex numbers for $x$?

Comment: @GEdgar:  I don't know where the tower converges in the complex plane, but presumably somebody does.  Once it converges you have to worry about branches of the log function as well.

Comment: @GEdgar if$$|W(-\ln(x!))|<1$$it converges, where $W$ is the Lambert $W$ function. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1674027/proving-that-if-w-ln-z-1-then-zzzz-is-convergent/1696352#1696352

Answer (score 4):

I would say that everything looks fine, as long as you define that $x! = \Gamma(x+1)$.

Comment: That indeed is my implicit assumptions. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you define $x!$ to be equal to $\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-t}t^x \mathrm{d}t$, then you can say the following:

$y = (x!)^{y} = (\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-t}t^x \mathrm{d}t)^y$

Raising both sides to the power of $\frac{1}{y}$:

$y^\frac{1}{y} = \int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-t}t^x \mathrm{d}t$.

Since the derivative of $y^\frac{1}{y}$ with respect to $y$ is $-y^\frac{1}{y}(\ln(y)-1)$, and by the Leibniz rule, the derivative of $\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-t}t^x \mathrm{d}t$ with respect to $x$ is $\int_{0}^{\infty}\ln(t)e^{-t}t^x \mathrm{d}t$, implicit differentiation tells us that:

$-y^\frac{1}{y}(\ln(y)-1)\mathrm{d}y = (\int_{0}^{\infty}\ln(t)e^{-t}t^x \mathrm{d}t)\mathrm{d}x$

We can solve for $\frac{\mathrm{dy}}{\mathrm{dx}}$:

$\frac{\mathrm{dy}}{\mathrm{dx}} = \frac{\int_{0}^{\infty}\ln(t)e^{-t}t^x \mathrm{d}t}{-y^\frac{1}{y}(\ln(y)-1)}$

We can simplify the denominator. Since $y=(x!)^y$, we can conclude that $y^\frac{1}{y}=x!$ and also that $\ln(y)=y\ln(x!)=x!^{x!^{x!^{.^{.^.}}}}\ln(x!)$. Substituting this into the denominator gives:

$\frac{\mathrm{dy}}{\mathrm{dx}} = \frac{\int_{0}^{\infty}\ln(t)e^{-t}t^x \mathrm{d}t}{-x!(x!^{x!^{x!^{.^{.^.}}}}\ln(x!)-1)}$

And there's the derivative.