# For what $k$ does $ \lim_{n \to \infty} k \uparrow\uparrow n $ converge?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

Let $k \in \mathbb{R}$; for what $k$ does

$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} k \uparrow\uparrow n $$

converge?

Note: The double up-arrow refers to [Knuth’s up-arrow notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%27s_up-arrow_notation), so $k \uparrow\uparrow n$ means $n$ levels of $k^{k^{\dots}}$.

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/890319/convergence-of-tetration-sequence) for the precise result.

Comment: The explanation of Knuth's notation is short enough to be included in your text. Avoid asking the reader to go to an entire article.

Comment: To be precise: is $k\uparrow\uparrow 2$ meant to be $(k^k)^k$ or is it $k^{(k^k)}$ ?

Comment: @KurtG. Power towers are always calculated from above (from right), this is a convention. The reason is that this way we usually get the largest possible number.

Comment: This has already been asked here (see the above comment).

Comment: @Peter . I knew the answer. My point was that there is a very inexpensive an reader-friendly way to clarify that notation every time it is introduced. But that view might be opinion based.

Comment: Thanks Gary! Closed this question.

Answer (score 0):

This answer only covers the case of positive $k$. For $k \in (0, 1]$ the limit trivially converges. The case $k > 1$ is covered below.

#### finding upper bound

Assuming the limit converges to a real number $x$, we have

\begin{align}
k^x &= x \\
x \ln k &= \ln x \\
\ln k &= \frac{\ln x}{x} =: f(x)
\end{align}

The function $f$ looks [like this](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Log%5Bx%5D/x). WolframAlpha tells us that

$$ \max_{x > 0} f(x) = f\left( \frac{1}{e} \right) = \frac{1}{e} $$

Therefore the upper bound of $k$ is

$$ k_0 = e^{1/e} \approx 1.445 $$

#### proof

Now we need to prove our assumption above, i.e. the limit does converge within the entire interval $(1, k_0]$. First pick any $k$ in the interval. Let $x_0$ be a solution to $k^x = x$ with the given $k$; from the plot we can see that $k > 1 \implies x_0 > 1$. Then, construct a sequence $\{a_n\}$ such that $a_0 = 1$, and $a_{i+1} = k^{a_i}$ (in other words, $a_n = k \uparrow\uparrow n$) for all natural number $i$. The first few terms look like

$$ a_1 = k, \quad a_2 = k^k, \quad a_3 = k^{k^k}, \quad \ldots $$

Since $a_0 = 1 < x_0$, and for any $i \in \mathbb{N}$

$$ a_i < x_0 \quad \implies \quad a_{i+1} = k^{a_i} < k^{x_0} = x_0 $$

By induction we know that the entire sequence $\{a_n\}$ is strictly smaller than $x_0$. In addition, we know that $a_1 = k > 1 = a_0$, and for any positive $i$ we have

$$ a_i > a_{i-1} \quad \implies \quad a_{i+1} = k^{a_i} > k^{a_{i-1}} = a_i $$

By induction we know that the sequence $\{a_n\}$ is strictly increasing. In other words, the sequence is bounded in interval $[1, x_0)$. Because the metric space for $\mathbb{R}$ (with the canonical metric and order operator) is compact, monotonic and bounded sequence converges. Q.E.D.

Comment: This question is a duplicate. The answer is already in the above link.