# How would the graph of $y=x^{x^{x^{x^\cdots}}}$ appear?

Tags: recreational-mathematics

Image you had the graph where $x$ is raised to itself an infinite amount of times.

Like this:
$$y=x^{x^{x^{x^\cdots}}}$$

What would this graph look like, and/or how is that computed?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/661608/391136 and https://math.stackexchange.com/q/166433/391136 and https://math.stackexchange.com/q/492109/391136

Comment: Thanks, but I don’t see how any of these are the same question.

Comment: The first link tells you that this is called an infinite tetration, how it is computed, and where it converges. The [wikipedia entry on tetration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetration#Infinite_heights) has a graph over the real and over the complex numbers.

Comment: Can't we write this as $y=x^y$

Answer (score 0):

Well, $y=x^{x^{x^{x^{...}}}}, y=x^y$

Using Wolfram the plot would look like this [image]

Answer (score 0):

The explicit solution of $y=x^y$ is given in terms of Lambert function
$$y=-\frac{W(-\log (x))}{\log (x)}$$ and, in the real domain, it is bounded at $x=e^{\frac{1}{e}}$.

Naman Jain's answer gives the plot of it.

Comment: Why is it that there is a bound at this spot?

Comment: @JoeyPeluka. Because, in the real domain, $W(t)$ is defined if $t\geq -\frac 1e$. Have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function